# How do I show that $[\sqrt{n}] - [\sqrt{n-1}] = 1$ when $n $ is a perfect square and $0$ otherwise for $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

> How do I show that $[\sqrt{n}] - [\sqrt{n-1}] = 1$ when $n $ is a
> perfect square and $0$ otherwise for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Here $[.] $ is
> the floor function.

For $n = k^2$ $ \rightarrow  [\sqrt{n}] = [k] = k $

$[\sqrt{n-1}] = [\sqrt{k^2-1}] < [\sqrt{k^2}]\;\; (=k)$

How can I show $[\sqrt{n-1}] > k-2$?

Also, I have no idea to attempt this when $n$ is not a perfect square. Please help me

Comment: You know that $(k-2)^2=k^2-4k+4=n-4(k-1)\le n-4$ for $n\ge 2$.

Answer (score 0):

The square root function is monotonic increasing and $n-1$ is never a perfect square if $n$ is (why?). This means it must be between the two perfect square roots, which is to say between $k$ and $k-1$ and so the floor must be $k-1$.

Comment: One minor exception to your statement "... $n-1$ is never a perfect square if $n$ is (why?)" is the case $n = 1$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan yeah if include zero in the naturals than there is one exception.

Comment: The question says $n \in \mathbb{N}$, not $n - 1 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan how are you defining $-1$ on $\mathbb{N}$? There is no predecessor  of $1$ if zero isn't natural. I'm not willing to believe it exist.

Comment: I'm not defining $-1$ on $\mathbb{N}$. The only $n$ value I'm referring to is $n = 1$. In that case, $n = 1 = 1^2$ is a perfect square. Also, $n - 1 = 0 = 0^2$ is a perfect square as well. My comment was this was the one exception to your statement, with it *only* requiring $n = 1$ satisfying $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so it's part of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

$n=k^2$ implies $\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor=\lfloor k\rfloor=k$ as you wrote.

Then $\lfloor \sqrt {n-1}\rfloor=k-1$ follows from $k-1<\sqrt {n-1}<k$; the second inequality is trivial, the first one is true since if you square you get $k^2-2k+1=n-2k+1<n-1$ which is true iff $2<2k$, that is $k\ge2$.

So this last argument works for $n$ perfect square $\ge4$. You do by hand the case $n=1$.

If otherwise $n$ is not a square, you want to prove that $\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor=\lfloor \sqrt{n-1}\rfloor$. Call $m=k^2$ the biggest square less than $n$, that is $m\le n-1$. You can see that
$$
m=k^2\le n-1<n<(k+1)^2
$$
from which you can conclude.